# Why is tautomers not possible in benzoquinone?

Tags: cis-trans-isomerism

[image]1,4-Benzoquinone, commonly known as para-quinone, is a chemical compound with the formula $\ce{C6H4O2}$

When there are alpha Hydrogen's why can't it show tautomerism?

Comment: Look at the supposed tautomer.

Answer (score 5):

You could sort of devise a tautomer by transferring an $\alpha$ hydrogen from carbon to oxygen.  But if you draw the resulting structure you find a pair of cumulated double bonds.  That tends to be unstable, and since the cumulated double-bonded carbons favor a 180° bond angle putting them into a relatively small ring makes them a lot more unstable.  Your proposed tautomer is way out there in energy.

Tautomerization of a ketone works better when you have an $\alpha$ hydrogen **on a saturated carbon atom**.